# negative lookbehind assertion in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a match `[abc]`, but not `[[abc]]` using Python regular expression.

I use negative lookbehind assertion `(?<!)` to filter out the `[[abc]]` as follows.

```
link = r"((?<!\[)\[([^<].+?) \s*([|] \s* (.+?) \s*)?])"
compLink = re.compile(link, re.X | re.U)
```

However, it doesn't work as first bracket in `[[...` satisfies condition unless the first bracket checks the next one is not `[`.

```
>>> a = compLink.findall("[[abc|Hi]]")
>>> a
[('[[abc|Hi]', '[abc', '|Hi', 'Hi')]
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(?<!\[)\[([^][]+)]|\[([^][]+)](?!])
```

The content is in group 1 or 2

*Note: re options are not needed here.*

If you need only to extract the deepest level of square brackets, these patterns suffice:

```
\[([^][]+)]         # for the whole substring (with a capturing group)
```

or

```
(?<=\[)[^][]+(?=])  # for the content only (i.e. the whole match)
```

Note that a closing square bracket in a character class doesn't need to be escaped if you put it at the first position.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the interior to “no  brackets” and check for a matching double (this is easier expressed as the regular expression):

```
(?!\[\[[^\]]*\]\])(?:^|.)(\[[^\]]*\])(?:.|$)
```

(Take only the captured group)

Answer (score 0):

I could find a match by having only one `(?<!\[)\[([^[]` bracket.

```
link = r"((?<!\[)\[([^[].+?) \s*([|] \s* (.+?) \s*)?])"
                      ^
compLink = re.compile(link, re.X | re.U)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this part `"((?<!\[)\[` with this `"((?<!\[)\[(?!\[)`
and leave the rest of the expression as is.